# do I need a return after throwing exception (c++ and c#)

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I have a function that generate an exception. For example the following code:

```
void test()
{
    ifstream test("c:/afile.txt");
    if(!test)
    { 
         throw exception("can not open file");
    }
    // other section of code that reads from file.
}
```

Do I need a return after throwing the exception?

What is the case in c#?

Comment: it's a void function so u don't need to return any value.

Comment: No, you don't need any return

Comment: After throwing an exception, you do not need to return because throw returns for you.

Comment: Throwing will bubble up the call stack to the next exception handler so returning is not required.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`throw` usually causes the function to terminate immediately, so you even if you do put any code after it (inside the same block), it won't execute. This goes for both C++ and C#. However, if you throw an exception inside a `try` block and the exception gets caught, execution will continue in the appropriate `catch` block, and if there is a `finally` block (C# only), it will be executed whether an exception is thrown or not. At any rate, any code immediately after the `throw` will never be executed.

(Note that having a `throw` directly inside a `try`/`catch` is usually a design problem - exceptions are designed for bubbling errors up across functions, not for error handling within a function.)

Comment: Well, technically, you *can* have something there, but it will never execute.

Comment: @Angew: Fair enough; I reformulated my answer. :-)

Comment: Have a +1 :-) It might also be worth mentioning there's no `finally` in C++.

Comment: however, microsoft made some ms-specific equivalents to account for the finally missing thing, i think it's __finally, but there doesnt seem to be one for gcc

Comment: @osirisgothra: [Apparently so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xtt5hxz.aspx), but it seems to be unrelated to regular C++ exceptions (and unportable, as you point out).

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't need to return, because after the exception is thrown the code after that wont' be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking throwing will NOT necessarily terminate the function immediately always.... as in this case,

```
try {

     throw new ApplicationException();


} catch (ApplicationException ex) {
    // if not re-thrown, function will continue as normal after the try/catch block

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

and then there is the Finally block - but after that it will exit.

So **no**, you do not have to return.

Answer (score 1):

After you call `throw` the method will return immediately and no code following it will be executed. This is also true if any exceptions are thrown and not caught in a `try / catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a void method you will never need a return instruction.

Then you can't put anything after the throw instruction it will never be used if something is throw

```
void test()
{
    ifstream test("c:/afile.txt");
    if(!test)
    { 
         throw exception("can not open file");
         // If there is code here it will never be reach !
    }
    // other section of code that reads from file.
    //if you place code here it will be reach only if you don"t throw an exception, so only if test == true in your case
}
```